# Accidental override kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I have this class

```
open class BaseActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_base)
  }
}
```

being superclass of this

```
class MainActivity : BaseActivity() {

  protected fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
  }
}
```

and got an error: accidental override the declarations:
protected open onCreate() 
protected final onCreate()

Comment: Can you share the whole, exact error message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to explicitly mark functions with the `override` keyword to override them (as described in the documentation [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#overriding-methods)):

```
class MainActivity : BaseActivity() {

  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
  }

}
```

If you leave out this keyword, the compiler will think that you've accidentally named a function the same as another function in the base class, hence the warning about an "accidental override".

You can also drop the `protected` keyword as this method will already have that visibility from the declaration in the `AppCompatActivity` base class.